# nested array condition in TYPO3 10.4 LTS

Tags: conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I need a typoscript condition working under TyYPO3 10.4 LTS

I tried

```
[page["siteLayout"]["headerlarge"] == "yes"]
```

with several variants like '' or () or point between.

However, none of them is working. Could you please point me to a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

As the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Conditions/Index.html) shows your syntax is correct.

But is your data structure correct?

As page is a database record I think you have no 2nd dimension.

Are you looking for something like:

```
[page["siteLayout"] == "headerlarge"]
```